# messages lost due to rate-limiting

Tags: rsyslog

We are testing the capacity of a Mail relay based on RHEL 7.6.
We are observing issues when sending an important number of msgs (e.g.: ~1000 msgs in 60 seconds).
While we have sent all the msgs and the recipient has received all the msgs, logs are missing in the /var/log/maillog_rfc5424.

We have the following message in the /var/log/messages:

```
rsyslogd: imjournal: XYZ messages lost due to rate-limiting
```

We adapted the /etc/rsyslog.conf with the following settings but without effect:

```
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0  # turn off rate limit
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 0     # turn rate limit off
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is from imjournal, but your configuration settings are for imuxsock.
According to the [rsyslog configuration](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html) page you need to set

```
$imjournalRatelimitInterval 0
$imjournalRatelimitBurst 0
```

Note that for very high message rates you might like to change to imuxsock, as it says:

> this module may be notably slower than when using imuxsock. The journal provides imuxsock with a copy of all “classical” syslog messages, however, it does not provide structured data. Only if that structured data is needed, imjournal must be used. Otherwise, imjournal may simply be replaced by imuxsock, and we highly suggest doing so.